# how can i disable one section-update after one time set in crud operation

Tags: asp.net, angular, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, crud

I created one crud operation in the two sections Create-date and Update-date. when I create any entity the create-date automatic assign in create date section and update-date section will disabled. and when I update the entity only the update date automatically changed on that date and disabled create-date

```html
 <div class="my-3">
                        <label class="form-label" for="Lead_CreateOn">{{ l('CreateOn') }}</label>
                        <input
                            required
                            class="form-control m-input"
                            #Lead_CreateOn
                            type="datetime"
                            bsDatepicker
                            datePickerLuxonModifier
                            [(date)]="lead.createOn"
                            id="Lead_CreateOn"
                            name="Lead_CreateOn"

                        />
                        <validation-messages [formCtrl]="Lead_CreateOn"></validation-messages>
                    </div>

                    <div class="my-3">
                        <label class="form-label" for="Lead_UpdateOn">{{ l('UpdateOn') }}</label>
                        <input
                            required
                            class="form-control m-input"
                            #Lead_UpdateOn
                            type="datetime"
                            bsDatepicker
                            datePickerLuxonModifier
                            [(date)]="lead.updateOn"
                            id="Lead_UpdateOn"
                            name="Lead_UpdateOn"
                        />
                        <validation-messages [formCtrl]="Lead_UpdateOn"></validation-messages>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

how can I disable one section after creating that entity like I have to disable Create-date when we are doing the edit in crud operation. because Create date we can set only one time only. i am using angular and asp.netzero.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done fully with Angular, no need for the backend:

1- Add a boolean to tell if you're/not on the editing mode.

2- Disable the date picker based on that boolean.

Example :
In the component.ts : `let isEditMode = false;`

and when you start editing set `isEditMode` to true and it should disable the date-picker.

In the component.html :  `<mat-datepicker [disabled]="isEditMode"></mat-datepicker>`

Comment: it is helpfull but i cannot use mat-datepicker

Comment: can you connect with me

Comment: Update your question with the code, I'll look into it

Comment: hey i updated it i want to know how I can write ts code